# 3 columns, center: fixed, side: fluid, right side: negative margin and placed over center

Tags: html, css

How to achieve this kind of layout: http://jsfiddle.net/47d4f/ 
BUT with column C (right side column) overlaying the center fixed column with width increased by 200px?

So the right side column should have like `margin-left:-200px` (or other solution to put it over center div) and still stick to the right side of the page.

Is it possible without JS?

Comment: I have no idea what you're going for. Have you tried anything yourself yet? If so, could you be so kind as to show us?

Comment: Please take a look at above Fiddle. I am trying to put a part (like 200px or any other fixed amount) of right column over the center column and still have left column with fluid width and the rest of right column with fluid width (stick to the edge of page).

Comment: Add another absolutely positioned div in the right column width a negative margin and a superior z-index?

Comment: Worked with position:relative. Thank you! Now it looks easy.